# Solve differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with this equation. I don't know how to solve this because I can't split $y$ from $x$.

$$2x \frac{dy}{dx} -y = x-1$$

$$y(4) = 3$$

$$x>0$$

Comment: the homogenous system is of 
Euler type

Comment: and the inhomogenous solution can be solved by educated guessing (it is not so difficultt)

Comment: @davoid: **Hint:** Integrating Factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution goes as follows:

$$2x \frac{dy}{dx} - y = x - 1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{y}{2x} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2x}$$

The integrating factor in this case is $e^{\int - \frac{dx}{2x} } = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

So we get by multiplying the integrating factor,

$$x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{y}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot x^{-\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$d\left(yx^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right) =\frac{1}{2}\cdot x^{-\frac{1}{2}} dx - \frac{1}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}} dx$$

Integrating both sides, we get 
$$\int d\left(yx^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right) =\int \frac{1}{2}\cdot x^{-\frac{1}{2}} dx - \int \frac{1}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}} dx$$
$$yx^{-\frac{1}{2}} =x^{\frac{1}{2}} + x^{-\frac{1}{2}} + c$$
where $c$ is a constant of integration.

Hence the solution is $$y=x+cx^\frac{1}{2}+1$$
Using the given condition, we have that $y(4)=3 \Rightarrow c=-1$

Thus the particular solution is $$y=x-x^\frac{1}{2}+1$$

Comment: I don't understand those 2 lines. Why you write d(y*x^-1/2) ?  $$x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{y}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot x^{-\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$d\left(yx^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right) =\frac{1}{2}\cdot x^{-\frac{1}{2}} dx - \frac{1}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}} dx$$

Comment: @davoid $d$ means differential. I just broke the $d/dx$ into $d$ and $dx$.

Comment: Ok, but what about $\frac{y}{2x^\frac{3}{2}}$ ? You multiplied both sides by dx right ? On the left side, first element is d(yx^-1/2) but the second element is missing.